# Adding HighLightJS to rails 7.1 with ImportMaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I'm trying to add HightlightJS

```
# importmap.rb    
pin "highlightjs", to: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"

// application.js
import hljs from "highlightjs"
```

Which gives error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default
```

I'm trying to use the simple quickstart here:
https://highlightjs.org/

What am I doing wrong?  Importmaps? Or HighlightJS?  How do I get it working?

The root of the problem was I was doing this:

```
bin/importmap pin highlightjs                                                                                                                                                         ✹
Pinning "highlightjs" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:highlightjs@9.16.2/highlight.pack.js
```

and then breaking it worse by editing the importmap entry to the up to date but not ES module version.

As per @alex answer, it needs to be this:

```
bin/importmap pin highlight.js                                                                                                                                                        ✹
Pinning "highlight.js" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:highlight.js@11.9.0/es/index.js
```

Comment: hi Will i didn't try it but can you try something like that if it will work (./bin/importmap pin highlightjs --download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ES module package:
*https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#es6-modules-omit-in-toc*

```rb
pin "highlight.js", to: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/es/highlight.min.js"
```

```js
import hljs from "highlight.js"
```

---

Or just use `importmap` command:

```bash
bin/importmap pin highlight.js
```

```js
import hljs from "highlight.js"
```

Comment: thanks,  yes I had tried using the pin task, but it got an old version (see my edit above).  Is there somewhere I could have looked up the correct packagename to pin, highlgiht.js not highlightjs ?

Comment: @Will yes, you can search on https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlight.js or https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/highlight.js etc...

Comment: ok great, thanks!